# Is a print version of a page considered as duplicate content

Tags: google-search, duplicate-content, print

On my websites, I have not put a print button.  However, right-clicking and **Print** gives the user a print version of any page.

This is identical to the normal page except

- it's missing menus from the top and bottom of the pages.
- it's missing shadows on boxes.
- the canonical points to the original page.

Since I do not have a menu, button or link for **Printing**, would this be considered as a duplicate page?  There are two considerations

- To avoid penalties
- To ensure the original page gets indexed, not the print version.

#### EDIT:

To clarify, I don't have a different page for printing.  I have deliberately not provided a link to a printed version.  Instead, I am using `@media print {}` in the **CSS** to handle it.

I guess the first question then, is **Will GSE activate the right-click print menu** for indexing?  If it won't, then the other questions/concerns are moot.

Comment: Does the print version of your page have the same URL? If it does, then there should be no duplication issue. If the URL is different (e.g. php page with different parameter in the end), then putting the canonical tag should put everything in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concerns are moot.   Google will recognise that there is a single page and won't see a duplicate version of it - indeed the "@media print" means its not a separate page, its a formatting of the canonical page for printing.  (Conceptually this would be little different to having a mobile vs desktop version of a site - Google recognises its the same page, formatted differently)

(Also, last I looked - although it was a while ago -  [the "duplicate content" penalty is a myth.](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty)  Google will try and work out one that is preferred and stick with it - it won't penalize the site for having the same content on 2 pages).